# npm run build fails with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a node/express/react application I am building using create-react-app for the client side. Whenever I run `npm run build` I get this error:

```
> frontend@0.1.0 build /Users/crescentfresh/myApp/client
> react-scripts build

module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv-expand'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at dotenvFiles.forEach.dotenvFile (/Users/crescentfresh/myApp/client/node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js:43:5)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/crescentfresh/myApp/client/node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js:41:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/crescentfresh/.npm/_logs/2018-10-09T23_53_36_314Z-debug.log
```

This is my package.json for my create-react-app directory:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@uppy/core": "^0.27.3",
    "@uppy/dashboard": "^0.27.5",
    "@uppy/react": "^0.27.5",
    "@uppy/tus": "^0.27.5",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.5",
    "apollo-client": "^2.3.5",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.2",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.0",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.4",
    "apollo-link-state": "^0.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.3",
    "react-spinners": "^0.4.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "recompose": "^0.29.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=3003 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

This used to build but recently began failing. I tried removing the packages that were added sometime before the failed builds happened but that didn't help (uppy and axios packages) so I am not sure if that's even related.

If there's anything else I should include please let me know.

Comment: it is most likely because of Node.js version. try to use stable version of node and you also can use nvm in order to switch between different versions

Comment: @SaJed I am using 8.1.1 that should be stable right?

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing module 'dotenv-expand'?

Comment: @crescentfresh 8.1.1 is stable, have you tried to reinstall create-react-app ?

Comment: @SaJed I will give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please run this command to resolve the error.

```
npm i dotenv-expand
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems that may lead to this problems i.e,React,npm,the package source.Maybe run this in terminal

`npm i --save-dev dotenv-expand / yarn add --save-dev dotenv-expand`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This resolved the error but left me with a new one. I'm thinking something is corrupted and I should just clone my repo again and start over. My friend isn't getting the same error on his machine so I have to assume I have something screwy in my local environment.